# Using Remainder or Factor Theorems to Find Coefficient

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm studying the remainder and factor theorems and a question asks:

> -4 is a root of  $x^4 + ax^3 - 19x^2 - 46x + 120$  What is the value of a?

Since -4 is a root then I can deduce that x+4 is a factor of the polynomial. But that's as far as I get.

Hints?

Comment: Just plug in $-4$, set the result equal to $0$, nothing fancy.

Comment: Note $-4$ is a root of the quadratic part, so a root of $\,(x\!+\!a)x^3,\,$ so a root of $\,x\!+\!a,\,$ so $\,a = \,\ldots\ \ $

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm not fully understanding what it means for something to be a 'root'.

Comment: A root of a polynomial $P(x)$ is just a value such that when $x=\text{the root}$, $P(x)=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^4+ax^3-19x^2-46x+120$. We say that $-4$ is a root of $f(x)$ if $f(-4)=0$.

Thus
$$(-4)^4+a(-4)^3-19(-4)^2-46(-4)+120=0.$$
Simplify, and solve for $a$.

**Remark:** The problem setter chose the numbers to make  the final answer very simple.

Answer (score 1):

The remainder theorem says if $a$ is a root of a degree $n$ polynomial $p(x)$, that is, if $p(a) = 0$, then $$(x-a) | p(x)$$ or equivalently, we can write $$p(x) = (x-a)q(x)$$ for some polynomial $q(x)$ with degree $n-1$.

However, you don't need to apply that here.  If $-4$ is a root, then $p(-4) =  0$.  If you evaluate your polynomial for $x=-4$ you get an equation with $a$ as unknown.

What is this equation?

You can then solve it for $a$.